# What is the difference between `command` and `./command`?

Tags: command-line, executable, execute-command

I found that sometime I use the `command` to run a command, but sometime I use the `./command` to run another command.

What is the difference?

Comment: I think that this question would become a bit more clear by substituting `xx` by `command` and `./xx` by `./command`.

Comment: @Exeleration-G I'm not sure changing `xx` to `command` necessarily makes this clearer. Consider that `command` itself is a command (a shell builtin). Without special formatting (like "**`command`**") to show that `command` is a [metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable), I think `xx` is better. A more common metasyntactic variable is [`foo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foo), but `xx` works just as well.

Comment: OK, well, `xx` is OK for me, too.

Answer (score 10):

Running `xx` searches the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable for a file called `xx`. The first executable it finds (whether a binary or a script), it executes. It does *not* look in the current directory, unless `.` is listed in `PATH`, which is *not* recommended.

Running `./xx` runs the file called `xx` that is located in the current directory, if there is an executable file with that name there.

To run a file by specifying its *location*, you must include a `/` symbol. If there is no `/` in the command (actually, the *first word* of the command, which is what identifies the name of the file to be executed), it searches `PATH` for it. If there is a `/`, then the first word of the command is taken to refer to a specific file by location.

Thus, `./xx` is different from `xx` because of the `/` that it contains.

Of course, `/xx` would *not* work properly--it would try to run a file called `xx` located in the root directory, `/`. Because `.` represents the current directory, `./xx` runs `xx` there.

Comment: So does it mean that `./xx` is same as `xx`?

Comment: No, it does not. It is also not what I read in the answer so why this comment?

Comment: I apologize, I mean if `./xx` is the same as `xx` if the xx script is locatted at the current directory?

Comment: @hguser: `./xx` and `xx` would be the same only if your current directory is on the `$PATH` and there wouldn't be any other executables named `xx` in dirs in `$PATH` before your cwd.

Comment: @hguser if you run `which xx` and it tells you `/usr/bin/xx`, then executing `xx` or `cd /usr/bin ; ./xx` will do the same... except for aliases or shell functions. For example, `ls` and `cd /bin ; ./ls` will probably show differences (the first with colors, the second without colors). That is because probably `ls` is an alias to `ls --color`. You can find if `xx` is an alias or is calling an executable in the disk using `type xx`.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós One small correction: By default in Ubuntu, the `ls` alias is to `ls --color=auto`. Thus `ls` produces colored output only when outputting directly to a terminal (when the color codes are likely to be properly interpreted and the colors shown correctly). Commands like `ls > logfile` or `ls | less` don't redirect or pipe color codes.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWERING IN SIMPLER WORDS:**

In Shell prompt we can execute commands... The command are nothing but the name of executable file kept in particular directory such as like : bin, sbin... We can call executable files without specifying the extension name.

```
user@comp~# command
```

When we enter command the file is executed kept in such particular directory.

```
user@comp~# ./command
```

In this case of using `./command` we are calling to executable file that is kept in the current prompt path (Present working Directory). You can get to know your current working directory of shell with command `pwd`.

Comment: for deep study...... read about environment variables.