# can't find executable file WSL2

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, executable, execute-command

i'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. I installed a program [libFM](http://www.libfm.org/) and followed the installation process (which is fairly simple). When I try to reach executable using `./libFM` it fails, returning the message "No such file or directory". When I specify the full address `/libfm-1.42.src/bin/libFM` it works fine.

I tried adding `/libfm-1.42.src/bin/libFM` to the `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc`, but it still returns the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add the **directory** to PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path):

```
PATH=$PATH:/libfm-1.42.src/bin/
```

After adding it, you can run `libFM` instead of `./libFM`. The latter will search for `libFM` in the current working dir only.

[See also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277331/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command)

Comment: Another short question on the matter, when I use ./ does it suppose to search recursively through the directories?

Comment: No. `./` means the current working dir, and only this. I linked a question that has some further explanations in the answers.